# Prefill database - nodejs + mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am using nodejs and mongodb to create a webapp. As I am currently working locally I'd like to use a local database which would already contain some elements so that my database is not empty everytime I run my program.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You can install mongo locally, or connect to a free one like MongoHQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Install mongodb locally http://www.mongodb.org/
2) Write a nodejs script to drop the collections if they exist, then insert new data into those collections
3) Run that script from the command prompt whenever you want to reset your test set.

I recommend using async to do your inserts in series. 
https://github.com/caolan/async

Drop:

```
var collections = ['users', 'products'];
async.each(collections, function(c, done){
 db.collection(c).drop(done);
});
```

Insert:

```
var users = db.collection(users);
var total = 0;
async.whilst(function(){ return total < 100; }, 
function(done) {
 users.insert({name: getNameString(), ...}, done);
}, function(){
 //all done
});
```

You'll want to have functions for generating names and other data. You can find lists online of common words and names, and pull from them: http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-5000.htm

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Mongo has some really good document and you ca find some here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/. You don't have to write a program as you can just create some js files to load data. Collections are created on the first insert.